# response.text only gets 200 OK

Tags: python-requests

Why am I just seeing 200 OK, I am not looking at the status?
This will send a dns lookup to my dns server to get an A Record back, i.e. ip address.

```
import requests
import json
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
url = "https://10.240.202.220/wapi/v2.7/record:host?name=www.google.com"
gm_user = 'admin'
gm_pwd = 'infoblox'
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=(gm_user, gm_pwd))
networks = json.loads(response.text)
print(response.text)
```

If I use postman, I get back the ip address correctly.

Comment: Actually i just get [ ]
the 200 is when i turn on debug and when i debug the variable response